# how to update install GCC 11.2 on windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, windows-10, mingw

I want to learn C. I have downloaded mingw from sourceforge.net but after installing it I realised that it installed version 6.3.0 of GCC. as I know  the latest version of GCC is 11.2. Does anybody know how to install latest version of GCC, and do I need to uninstall that mingw folder?

I'm on the windows 10

Comment: You can use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) on Windows to [install newer versions of GCC](https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2).

Comment: @Ruks do I need to delete c\MinGW folder first?

Comment: The current version of GCC msys2 provides is 10.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install MinGW-w64 gcc (for either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows) via MSYS2's package manager (`pacman`), or get a standalone build from https://winlibs.com which requires no installation - just unzip (can coexist alongside other MinGW versions).

If you're new to programming in C, I recommend using an IDE, like Code::Blocks for example.